# Applying Select Case

Tags: vba, excel

Current code is as follows:

```
For Each s In myReport.Sheets
    If s.Name = "Data" Then
        s.Activate
        Excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
    End If
    If Left(s.Name, 7) = "Charts_" Then
        s.Activate
        Excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 77
    End If
    If s.Name = "definitions" Then
        s.Activate
        Excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
    End If
    If s.Name = "Summary" Then
        s.Activate
        Excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 71
    End If
Next
```

Could this be made more efficient using a `Select Case`? I'm unsure how to apply `VBA` version of select case in this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my attempt using `Select Case` - though I'd prefer KazJaw's `If/ElseIf`, as it is even more flexible.

```
Dim z as Integer

For Each s in myReport.Sheets
    Select Case UCase(s.Name)
       Case "DATA": z = 80
       Case "DEFINITIONS": z = 75
       Case "SUMMARY": z = 71
       Case Else:
           If Left(s.Name, 7) = "Charts_" Then 
               z = 77
           Else
               z = 0
           End If
    End Select
    If z Then
        s.Activate
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = z
    End If
Next s
```

Alternatively, you can create a very flexible `Select Case` statement with the following trick:

```
For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Select Case True
       Case s.Name = "Data":             z = 80
       Case Left(s.Name, 7) = "Charts_": z = 77
       Case s.Name = "Defintions":       z = 75
       Case s.Name = "Summary":          z = 71           
       Case Else:                        z = 0
    End Select
    If z Then
        s.Activate
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = z
    End If
Next s
```

As you can see from the two examples, the first Select Case allows you to execute a central code for each comparison (e.g. the `UCase`, which is a good practise anyway), while the second gives you full flexibility - but is in the end nothing else then an `If/ElseIf/...` statement!

Comment: crickey....sad to say but I didn't realise a non-initialised integer evaluates to `False` either ( `If z Then` )

Comment: @whytheq: an integer cannot be "uninitialised", ie. `Nothing` or something similar. Instead, it's simply 0 (as is Long, Double, etc.)

Comment: ok Peter ....`Dim z as Integer` is just a _declaration_, or in `VBA` is it more? Or "is it more" for the primitive types whereas if we said `Dim z as object` then we could say z is uninitialsed ?

Comment: @whytheq: if you dim any primitive data type, it'll be automatically initialised to 0, as a primitive data type is just the variable itself and therefore cannot be "nothing". An object however is in reality a pointer to the actual object (memory). Thus, after dimming an object, it really is not initialised, i.e. `Nothing`, as the pointer is not yet pointing to any meaningful address. This only takes place when you use `Set` or dim it with the `New`keyword...

Answer (score 2):

This one would be more efficient:

```
For Each s In myReport.Sheets
    If s.Name = "Data" Then
        s.Activate
        Excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80

    ElseIf Left(s.Name, 7) = "Charts_" Then
        s.Activate
        Excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 77

    ElseIf s.Name = "definitions" Then
        s.Activate
        Excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75

    ElseIf s.Name = "Summary" Then
        s.Activate
        Excel.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 71
    End If
Next
```

In your code `If statements` are always checked four times. In my code they will be checked as long as the condition is not meet. Possibly only once, sometimes four time, sometimes in between. 
`Select Case` will not be good in your situation.

Comment: +1 thanks - should have got this myself but sometimes the obvious isn't obvious.

Comment: @whytheq, please keep in mind that my solution is more efficient compared to the one from Peter. My is approx. 10-15% faster. But I could admit- Peter's answer is nice looking one :)