# Assign variable to data

Tags: arrays, vb.net, if-statement

I'm trying to identify if data(0) = X1 then I would like to assign the value of data(1) = Y1 to a string(MyString1). So I later on can call MyString1, and then the value of MyString1 corresponds to Y1. And I should be able to repeat his procedure:

if data(0) = X2 then data(1) = Y2 should be assigned to MyString2 and so on.

I've simplified the data, they are more specific than X1 and Y1.

I've added my code below.

```
Dim cmd As Odbc.OdbcCommand = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(mystring, conn)
Dim reader As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
Dim columnCount As Integer
Dim MyString1 As String
Dim data As Object() = New Object(10) {}
conn.Open()
MsgBox("Connection Established!")
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read()
    columnCount = reader.GetValues(data)

     If data(0) = "X1" Then
         MyString1 = data(1).ToString()
     End If

    Debug.WriteLine(data(0))
    Debug.WriteLine(data(1))
        My.Forms.Form2.TypeTextBox.Text = MyString1
    End While
    conn.Close()
```

I hope this makes sense.

EDIT: My problem is that I'm going to have like 30 if blocks. Like this one:

```
If data(0) = "X1" Then
         MyString1 = data(1).ToString()
     End If
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do this smarter?

Comment: What's your problem then?

Comment: My problem is that I'm going to have like 30 If statements.
 If data(0) = "X1" Then
                MyString1 = data(1).ToString()
            End If
 If data(0) = "X2" Then
                MyString2 = data(1).ToString()
            End If

Comment: Sounds to me like a perfect example to use the [Select...Case Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx). Here is a sample Q&A to demonstrate its usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317630/applying-select-case

Comment: Retagged; This is VB.Net not VBA

Comment: Select/Case is definitely something I would look into. Thanks. Seems like the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not quite certain if I fully understand what you are looking for, but sound like a case for a simple "[If...Then...(Else)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/752y8abs.aspx)".
From your description I don't see the need to store Y2 in data(1) first.

```
If data(0) = X1 Then
    myString = Y2
End If
```

EDIT:
...ok, now I understand... can you do sth like this?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim data As Object() = New Object(30) {}
Dim myString As String() = New String(30) {}
For i = 0 To 30
  If data(i) = ("X" + &i+1) Then
    myString(i) = data(i+1).ToString()
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated my question now. My biggest issue is that I'm going to have like 30 if blocks.